Kubernetes. Не могу удалить pod
Kubernetes. Не могу удалить pod. Написал манифест с Job. Для миграции Django приложения в БД. При выполнении под переходит в состояние Error. И создаются почему то дубликаты подов. После чего мастер нода отваливается. И я теряю доступ к серверу в целом. Как это по фиксить?
NAME           STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION
kube-master    Ready    control-plane   134d   v1.29.4
kube-worker1   Ready    worker          134d   v1.29.4
kube-worker2   Ready    worker          134d   v1.29.4
root@kube-master:/home/dott# kubectl -n ktswebinar get pods
NAME               READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
migrations-md62p   0/1     Error    0          14h
migrations-mtknb   0/1     Error    0          14h
migrations-z4smk   0/1     Error    0          14h
root@kube-master:/home/dott# kubectl -n ktswebinar delete deploy --all
No resources found
root@kube-master:/home/dott# kubectl -n ktswebinar delete app-migrations.yaml
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "app-migrations"
root@kube-master:/home/dott# kubectl delete services --all
service "kubernetes" deleted
root@kube-master:/home/dott#

